# Raspberry Pi how to get data from serial port in GNU screen

Tags: gpio, screen, uart

I have sample app that wait on signal from IR sensor that is connected to GPIO15 and 14:

```
ser = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
io.add_event_detect(15,io.RISING, callback=inputLow, bouncetime=200)
def inputLow(channel):
  print('signal test')
```

And now I want to run screen: screen /dev/ttyAMA0 115200

- 1) I can only run screen because when I run above application I get
  error device ttyAMA0 is busy
- 2) when I run only gnu screen in    terminal I see only black screen,
  when I send signal to IR sensor on    the terminal nothing happens,
  screen is black

How can I read data from ttyAMA0?

Comment: What model Pi? Have you enabled serial?

Comment: RPi3, yes I've enabled

Answer (score 2):

There is **ABSOLUTELY NO REASON** to use `/dev/ttyAMA0` in a moderately up-to-date OS. This is connected to Bluetooth (by default) on Pi3 and PiZeroW.

In **ALL** models use `/dev/serial0` which is the default serial port (if enabled), even if ports are swapped.

See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Comment: my OS is Jessy, so I should use ttyS0 or /dev/serial0?

Comment: @Robert I don't know this `Jessy` but the earliest implementations of Raspbian supporting the Pi3 were half baked and poorly documented (which was the reason for my linked post), You can check if `/dev/serial0` exists.

Comment: ok, ls -l /dev and I see: ttyS0 and ttyAMA0 and serial0->ttyS0, serial1->ttyAMA0